# Mysql Regular expression for multibyte characters

Tags: mysql, regex

I have tried using REGEXP:

```
'^[A-Za-z0-9ÿ!#$%&*.?@ˆ^_¡\-¦¨¯´¸¿˜‘’‚“”„\'‹›¢£¤¥€±«»×÷§©¬®°µ¶·…†‡•‰¼½¾¹²³ªÇºß`]+$'
```

but it is also accepting the characters which are not there in RE like `ϢϗγΔ`.

Can any one help?

Comment: [Seems to be working okay to me](http://rubular.com/r/djVTNqEe1n).

Comment: I tested it with [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it worked correctly.

Comment: by "MySQL" I think perhaps you need to give us some MySQL details such as your SQL collation and connection charset and exactly how this regex is meant to interact with your SQL queries?

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/79226

Comment: SQL collation is utf8_unicode_ci and characterset is utf8.This is the query that I have used for the RE       SELECT s.*,102 as error_code
       from cs_eligibility_file_staging s
       where member_first_name not  REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9–—ÿ !#$%&*.? @@ˆ^_¡\-¦¨¯´¸¿˜‘’‚“”„\'‹›¢£¤¥€±«»×÷§©¬®°µ¶·…†‡•‰¼½¾¹²³ªÇºß`]+$'
       and s.member_first_name is not null 
       and s.member_first_name <> ''
       and s.file_id = 961;

Comment: Your regex in that comment doesn't seem to be the same regex you've listed above. Is that a SO induced problem?

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP in MySQL only handles bytes, *not* multi-byte characters.

On the other hand, your set of characters seems to be entirely in the `latin1` character set.

So, I suggest that you convert your string to latin1, then test with the REGEXP (to avoid the few characters missing), then convert back and see if you got more `?` than you started with.  Question marks would indicate that the conversion *to* latin1 failed because of the lack of a latin1 encoding for some character(s).

Please describe the *intent* of your query; there may be a simpler way to approach it.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Your answer gave me a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed,its the problem with the collation I have changed the collation to utf8_general_ci from utf8_unicode_ci.